# Pressing enter leaves ContentEditable box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to send information after someone enters some information, it sends if someones leaves by clicking somewhere else, or tabbing out.... But when pressing enter, it  breaks and go to the next line. I'm trying to prevent that and just leave the box when they press enter.

Code:

```
$('.username').blur(function(){
    if (username != $(this).text()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'usernameChange',
            data: { username: username, id: id }
        }).done(function(msg){
            console.log('Okay, new username is ' + msg);
        });
    }
});
```

How do I check if someone presses enter to leave...

```
<span class="username" contenteditable="true">Nasus</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to handle the keydown event, to lose focus on contentEditable when someone presses the Enter key, this way you also prevent line break.

```
$(".username").on("keydown",function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;  // ie||others
    if(key == 13)  // if enter key is pressed
        $(this).blur();  // lose focus
});
```